# Weird error while creating a histogram from SQL Data

Tags: r, shiny

Not entirely sure where this error is even coming from. Here is the error:

> ```
> Error in match.arg(tolower(breaks), c("sturges", "fd", "freedman-diaconis", 'arg' should be one of “sturges”, “fd”,
> ```
>
> “freedman-diaconis”, “scott”

And here is my code:

```
    library("RODBC")
datalithicdb <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQLServer};server=CGPC-TECH1\\SQLEXPRESS;database=datalithic;trusted_connection=true;")

boedata <- sqlQuery(datalithicdb, "select EUROil, WellID from vwWellNames where EUROil <>0")

med<-median(boedata$EUROil)
l=1/10*med
h=9/10*med

truncboedata <- subset(boedata, EUROil>l & EUROil<h)
hist(
  truncboedata$EUROil, 
  main= "OIL EUR Histogram", 
  freq=FALSE,
  probability = TRUE, 
  xlab="EUR",
  ylab="# of Wells", 
  col="green",border = "blue", 
  las=1, 
  breaks=Bin Size
  )
close(datalithicdb)
```

Here is the ui.R file

```
    library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Oil EUR Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      "Slider",
      sliderInput(inputId = "Bin Size",
                  label = "Number of Bins",
                  value = 100, min = 1,max = 1000)),
    mainPanel(

    )
   )
  )
 )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What the error is telling you is that the `breaks` argument must be one of “sturges”, “fd”, “freedman-diaconis”, “scott”. Currently you have it set as "Bin Size" which isn't a valid option. This isn't a problem with your SQL data

Comment: "Bin Size" is a slider input I have set up. What are those options? What does breaks="sturges" mean? I don't have anything about "sturges" in my code.

Comment: If it's a function you have set up, then don't include it in quotes. Currently it's thinking you are passing it a string, not the name of an object

Comment: That returns ab error saying

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  las=1, 
  breaks=Bin Size"

Comment: Is your function called `Bin Size`? If it is, then it shouldn't have a space in it

Comment: As far as *'What does breaks="sturges" mean?'*, just have a look at the documentation: `?hist` explains all the options nicely.

Comment: The idea is to put my histogram in the main panel, but as of now its not cooperating.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the example at the bottom of `?sliderInput`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
    min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
}
```

We can see that an input is defined with input ID `"obs"`. On the server side, it is referenced as `input$obs`. You need to mimic this style.

Where you have `breaks = Bin Size` you instead should have something like `breaks = input$Bin Size`, but even that won't work because proper variable names can't have spaces. You have a few options to deal with this:

1. Rename your input ID to not use spaces. I would just use `inputId = "n_bins"` and then use `breaks = input$n_bins`
2. Use backticks, R's way of demarcating a weird object name: `` input$`Bin Size` ``
3. Use a string for accessing the `input` list: `breaks = input[["Bin Size"]]`

As a side-note, I think you may be disappointed with the results -- they seem mislabeled. You're giving `hist` a suggestion about the number of breaks, which is inversely related to the number of bins. If a user wanted very large bins, the should set your slider to a very low number to have very few breaks.